# How to get an instance of the updated sequelize model from an afterUpsert hook?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Other sequelize hooks, like `afterUpdate(instance, options)` provide an instance of the modified model as a parameter. However, `afterUpsert(created, options)` provides a `created` boolean which indicates if the operation was a insert or update.

Is there a way to configure sequelize, or manipulate the `afterUpsert` parameters, to obtain an instance of the upserted model?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can not. As the `result` of `upsert` call to db via `queryInterface` is what is returned to the `afterUpsert` hook, which is `boolean` value whether there has been any newly created records or not in the `upsert` process.

While, you can use `beforeUpsert` with the values passed to `upsert` method. Not sure if that might be helpful *( may be to clear a cache )*

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue recently, and I was able to manage it this way:

```
beforeUpsert: (values, options)=>{
    /* afterUpsert will always get an array of type [Model, created] as first argument */
    options.returning = true;
},
```

I decided to use the beforeUpsert hook to make sure that any call to Model.upsert is forced to return an instance and not only a created boolean. But, you can also call

```
upsert(values,{returning: true});
```

HTH